# Kivy ProgressBar Popup not showing properly

Tags: python, popup, kivy, progress-bar, clock

I want to implement two kind of loading popups:

1. Popup gets called with pre-defined duration
2. Popup gets updated from other functions

The first popup works properly. However, the second popup wont show until the function is finished. I think i am missing a Clock.schedule_once somewhere, but i am not sure where exactly and how to implement it.

```
class BoxL(BoxLayout): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super(BoxL, self).__init__()

    def next(self, dt):
        if self.progress_bar.value>=100:
            return False
        self.progress_bar.value += 1
        if self.progress_bar.value == 100:
            self.popup.dismiss()

    def next_manually(self, dt):
        if self.progress_bar.value>=100:
            return False
        self.progress_bar.value = self.loadingValue
        if self.progress_bar.value == 100:
            self.popup.dismiss()
            self.loadingValue = 0

    def loading(self, *argv):
        if len(argv) == 1:
            loadingText = argv[0]
        if len(argv) == 2:
            loadingText = argv[0]
            loadingTime = argv[1]
        self.progress_bar = ProgressBar()
        self.popup = Popup(title='[b]Loading: [/b]' + loadingText,
                               title_size = 20,
                               title_align = 'center',
                               auto_dismiss = False,
                               size_hint = (None, None),
                               size = (384, 160),
                               content = self.progress_bar)
        if len(argv) == 2:
            self.popup.bind(on_open=
                            Clock.schedule_interval(self.next, loadingTime/100))
        if len(argv) == 1:
            self.popup.bind(on_open=
                            Clock.schedule_interval(self.next_manually, 5/100))
        self.progress_bar.value = 0
        self.popup.open()
```

And now the functions who actually call the popup(s):

```
    def test(self):
        self.loading('Testload', 5)
    
    def test2(self):
        self.loading('TestLoad2')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.loadingValue = 10
        time.sleep(1)
        self.loadingValue = 30
        time.sleep(1)
        self.loadingValue = 35
        time.sleep(1)
        self.loadingValue = 50
        time.sleep(1)
        self.loadingValue = 60
        time.sleep(1)
        self.loadingValue = 90
        time.sleep(1)
        self.loadingValue = 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show how `test2()` is called, but if it is executed on the main thread, then it will stop all other execution on the main thread for 7 seconds (the 7 calls to `sleep`). Then when it finishes the main thread can continue and the `ProgressBar` will be updated with the value of `loadingValue`, which be be `100` at that time. I think you need to put most of the `test2()` method in another thread. Try something like this:

```
def test2(self):
    self.loading('TestLoad2')
    threading.Thread(target=self.do_updates).start()

def do_updates(self):
    time.sleep(1)
    self.loadingValue = 10
    time.sleep(1)
    self.loadingValue = 30
    time.sleep(1)
    self.loadingValue = 35
    time.sleep(1)
    self.loadingValue = 50
    time.sleep(1)
    self.loadingValue = 60
    time.sleep(1)
    self.loadingValue = 90
    time.sleep(1)
    self.loadingValue = 100
```